# How to load servlet on startup using Jersey 2.3 with embedded Jetty

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jetty

I am migrating my Jersey web application from Jersey 1.17.1 to 2.3.1, using Jetty 9.0.6. With Jersey 1.17.1, the Resource would load during startup. However, pretty much the same code (below) only starts when a request comes in. But I would like to make sure it is loaded during startup (i.e., the constructor of the annotated resource class is called). Any idea what's wrong?

```
public static void startServer(){
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server = new Server();
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(context);
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer();
    org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(servletContainer);
    servletHolder.setInitParameter(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "mypackage");
    servletHolder.setInitOrder(0);  // this does not seem to work
    context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");
    server.start();
}
```

And roughly:

```
package mypackage;

@Singleton
@Path("/foo")
public class MyResource {

    public MyResource(){
        // I want this to be called when I start the server
    }

    @Path("bar")
    public Response receivePayload(@Context HttpServletRequest request, String payloadString){
        // do some stuff
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uli,

The servletHolder.setInitOrder(0) that you refer to is related to the org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer class. The unit tests for servlet init ordering in jetty-9.0.6 are passing, so I assume that the jersey ServletContainer class is in fact being loaded on startup as expected.

Perhaps jersey has changed behaviour between version 1.17 and 2.3 and only lazily initializes the resources mapped using the @Path annotation?

Or perhaps jersey has changed to use some servlet 3.0 features for initialization, such as ServletContainerInitializers? If that is the case, then you'll need to upgrade from a ServletContextHandler to a WebAppContext, and ensure that the support for these servlet 3.0 features are enabled (see jetty docs on using annotations with embedded jetty here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/using-annotations-embedded.html)

cheers
Jan

Comment: Thanks, Jan. It may indeed be that the behavior between 1.17 and 2.3 has changed in that regard. What I ended up doing is moving the code from the constructor to somewhere else, so that I am fine with the lazy initialization.